# If E is a Hilbert space and $T \in B(E)$ is compact, show $T(E)$ does not contain a closed infinite dimensional subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

It's the problem from "Essential Results of Functional Analysis," R.J. Zimmer, Chapter 3, problem 3.1.
I try to prove this problem and I am confused with the condition "closed infinite dimensional." Consider a compact operator T, given by diagonal matrix $T_{ij} = \lambda_i\delta_{ij}$, with $\lambda_i \to 0$. Then for Hilbert space $E$, we have $T(E) = E$. That means $T(E)$ has a closed infinite dimensional subspace($E$ itself). Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You don't have $T(E) = E$ for such an operator. The $\lambda_i \to 0$ condition ensures that only sequences that converge fast enough to $0$ are in $T(E)$ (I'm identifying $E$ with $\ell^2$ here via ONB).

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I still cannot understand very clearly. For any $x \in E$, we can take an orthonormal basis $e_i$ of $E$ and express $x$ as $\Sigma a_i e_i$. Thus I can construct $y = \Sigma \frac{a_i}{\lambda_i} e_i$ and $Ty = x$?

Comment: $$\sum \left\lvert \frac{a_i}{\lambda_i}\right\rvert^2$$ will in general be $\infty$, so the "inverse image" of $x$ isn't in $E$. Expressed differently, the inverse $T^{-1} \colon T(E) \to E$ isn't a bounded  linear operator.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks a lot, I think I got the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For each closed subspace $F \subset E$, there is an orthogonal projection $P_F$ onto $F$. The composition $P_F \circ T$ is also compact. So if $T(E)$ contained a closed infinite-dimensional subspace $F$, we'd have a compact map onto an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Why can that not happen?

Comment: I tried to use the method as the following: The map $F \cap T : E \to F \cap T(E)$ is compact. Since $F$ is infinite dimensional, we have an orthonormal basis $\{T(x_i)\}_i$. It is clear that $\{T(x_i)\}_i$ has no converge subsequence. But I stucked since I don't know if $\{x_i\}_i$ is bounded.

Comment: Try with the other characterisation of compact maps (the definition, usually), $K$ is compact if (and only if) $\overline{K(U)}$ is compact ($U$ is the unit ball in the space).

Comment: Thank you so much, I know how to do now. One question remained is that how can I prove the $P_F \circ T$ is a compact map? I have a basic idea: since $\overline{T(E_1)}$ is compact, for any open covering on $\overline{P_F \circ T(E_1)}$, we will have a corresponding open covering on $\overline{T(E_1)}$. But I don't know how to construct such correspondence very clearly.

Comment: You generally have the fact that the composition of a compact operator with a continuous operator is compact. Let $K$ be compact and $S$ continuous. Since $S$ is continuous and $\overline{K(U)}$ compact, $S(\overline{K(U)})$ is compact, in particular closed. But then we have $\overline{S(K(U))} \subset S(\overline{K(U)})$, so that is compact too, hence $S\circ K$ is compact. Composing on the other side, $S(U)$ is contained in a multiple of the unit ball by continuity, so $\overline{K(S(U))} \subset \overline{K(c\cdot U)} = c\cdot\overline{K(U)}$ is compact.

Comment: I tried the statements as following: suppose $F$ is infinite-dim subspace of $T(E)$, let $T_F:T(E)\to F$ be the projection. $\overline{T_F(T(E)\cap T(E_1))}=F\cap\overline{T_F\circ T(E_1)}$ is compact. Since F is infinite-dim, $\exists \{f_i\}_i\subset F$ orthonormal basis. But I don't know how to prove $\{f_i\}_i\subset \overline{T_F\circ T(E_1)}$. Maybe I got something wrong again?

Comment: By the open mapping theorem, $P_F(T(E_1))$ (if I haven't misunderstood, you denote the unit ball by $E_1$?) is a neighbourhood of $0$ in $F$. By compactness of $T$, it is relatively compact. So together that says $F$ is a locally compact space. But only finite-dimensional spaces are locally compact.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've got the solution:)